# Print fifo's content in bash

Tags: linux, bash, named-pipes, fifo

I want to get a fifo's content and print it in a file, and I have this code:

```
path=$1 #path file get from script's input
    if [ -p "$path" ];then #check if path is pipe

       content = 'cat "$path"'
       echo "$content" > output
       exit 33

    fi
```

My problem is that when I execute the `cat "$path"` line the script is stopped and the terminal displays the underscore.
I don't know how to solve this problem

P.S the fifo isn't empty and `output` is the file where I want to print fifo's content

Answer (score 1):

If the FIFO is not empty, and there are no longer any file descriptors writing to that FIFO, you'll get `EOF` in the `cat` command. From `man 7 pipe`:

> If all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been
>   closed, then an attempt to read(2) from the pipe will see end- of-file
>   (read(2) will return 0).

Source: [man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment statement is incorrect.

1. Whitespace around `=` is not permitted.
2. You're confusing single quotes with backquotes. However, you should use `$(...)` for command substitution anyway.

The correct assignment is

```
content=$(cat "$path")
```

or more efficiently in `bash`,

```
content=$(< "$path")
```